# Laravel - How to pass multiple values into function

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two different input values that I need to pass into a Laravel/Livewire function.

Here is my current input:

```
<button wire:click="addData({{ $name->id }})">Add Data</button>
```

Here is my input I would like to use:

```
<button wire:click="addData({{ $name->id, $name->Course_Name }})>Add data</button>
```

Inside of my function i would like it to be akin to:

```
public function addData($id, $Course_Name) {
     // Do stuff here
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#action-parameters , you'd need separate braces for each parameter

Comment: `addData({{ $name->id }}, {{ $name->Course_Name }})`. The `,` within `{{ , }}` would produce a syntax error, since anything inside of `{{ }}` is PHP code, and `$var1, $var2` is not valid PHP code in most situations (`[$var1, $var2]` is fine for example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting {{ $name->Course_Name }} in quotes in the component?

`<button wire:click="addData({{ $name->id, '$name->Course_Name }})'">Add data</button>`

Refer to this [thread](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/wire-click-doesnt-trigger-function-with-2-word-variables-passed-to-back-end/4068/6) for more information.